# Calling a certain function on any module / object

Tags: javascript, python

In JavaScript I have multiple different modules (objects) with a function named "one".

```
test_module1 = { 
    one: function () {
       alert('fun mod1_one successful'); 
    },
    two: function () {
       alert('fun mod1_two successful'); 
    }
}
test_module2 = { 
    one: function () {
       alert('fun mod2_one successful'); 
    },
    two: function () {
       alert('fun mod2_two successful'); 
    }
}

workingObj = test_module1;
workingObj["one"]();
```

Now, if I have one of these modules/objects in the variable "workingObj" and I want to call
the function "one" on this object, I call workingObj["one"]();.

At the moment I learn Python. Is in this language something similar?

I need a solution without Python classes/inheritance.

Thanks alot in advance

Wolfgang

Comment: Any particular reason you don't use `workingObj.one()`? Do you not know which method you'll be calling in advance?

Comment: Hello user2357112! In some situations I know the name of the function, in other I do not know.

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely! All you have to do is take advantage of "[getattr](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr)" and do the following

```
class MyObj(object):
    def func_name(self):
        print "IN FUNC!"

my_obj = MyObj()

# Notice the () invocation
getattr(my_obj, "func_name")() # prints "IN FUNC!"
```

Comment: Hello Bryan! How would a "my_obj" look like in Python? Thanks

Comment: Ah I'm sorry you needed more context, I've updated the answer accordingly

Comment: `getattr` may be overkill. Most likely, all you need is `my_obj.func_name()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`oprerator.methodcaller`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller)

```
from operator import methodcaller
call_one = methodcaller("one")
```

Now you can use `get_one` to get the `one` from any object and call it like this

```
call_one(obj)
```

**Advantage over `getattr`**

Apart from the fact that it is very readable and idiomatic, you don't have to call `methodcaller` for each and every object, unlike `getattr`. Create once and use it as long as you want with as many objects as you like.

For example,

```
class MyClass1(object):  # Python 2.x new style class
    def one(self):
        print "Welcome"

class MyClass2(object):  # Python 2.x new style class
    def one(self):
        print "Don't come here"

from operator import methodcaller
call_one = methodcaller("one")

obj1, obj2 = MyClass1(), MyClass2()
call_one(obj1)    # Welcome
call_one(obj2)    # Don't come here
```

Comment: If you're going to use `operator`, why not `operator.methodcaller`?